# Changing Date Format in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench

I currently have a Release_Date(Date) in my Songs table. I been trying to change the date format. The current format is yyyy-mm-dd. I want mm/dd/yyyy.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Error: Invalid Date value.

Answer (score 2):

`Release_Date` is stored in the database as a `Date`, not as a string, so you don't need to call the `str_to_date` function. You are getting an error because you are calling the `str_to_date` function on something that is already a date, not a string.

Furthermore, as it is a date, you can't update that field to a string value. You would have to create a new column defined as a string and store the date there.

However, it is highly advantageous to keep the dates stored as `Date` fields, because comparisons, sorting, and the various date functions will all work as they should.

So if you want to use the date in a different format, you would just use `DATE_FORMAT(Release_Date,'%m/%d/%Y')` whenever you access it, and leave the field as a native date, as in

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Release_Date,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM Songs WHERE Release_DATE IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "update" the internal format of a MySQL date.  If you want to *display* your text as `mm/dd/yyyy`, then you should only need a single call to `DATE_FORMAT`, e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-29', '%m/%d/%y')
```

which prints:

```
07/29/19
```

Comment: My dates are in a proper date format with datatype Date. They already exists in columns and I want to update the format.

Comment: You can't/don't need to do that.

Comment: MySQL dates are stored as 4 byte integers, not as readable strings. In effect, when you retrieve a date without explicitly formatting it, MySQL is formatting it to `YYYY-MM-DD` for you by default. The gory details are here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html

Answer (score 0):

As Tim suggests, you don't need to change the existing date format & value but if you insists, you could add another column - datatype VARCHAR - in the table and then update the column according to your desired date format. Steps are below:

- create new column

```
ALTER TABLE songs
ADD COLUMN `rls_date` VARCHAR(50) AFTER `release_date`;
```

- Update new column with desired date format

```
UPDATE songs SET `rls_date`=DATE_FORMAT(`Release_Date`,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

Just remember, by doing this, you can't expect the column to identify any date format related function outright. Lets say you run a query like this `SELECT * FROM songs WHERE rls_date=CURDATE();` won't work.